# Flash-cc when i go to next Fram shows {Error #2007: Parameter child must be non-null ! }

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, flash-cc

This is how I do it but when it gotonext frame it shows error

> Error #2007: Parameter child must be non-null.    at
>
> flash.display::DisplayObjectContainer/addChild()   at
>
> test_fla::MainTimeline/fl_EnterFrameHandler_2()

Fram1:

```
var fl_NC:NetConnection = new NetConnection();
fl_NC.connect(null);    

var fl_NS:NetStream = new NetStream(fl_NC);
fl_NS.client = {onPlayStatus: myCallBack};

var fl_Vid:Video = new Video();
fl_Vid.attachNetStream(fl_NS);
var num:int=0;

stage.addChild(fl_Vid);


fl_NS.play("http://127.0.0.1/part1video.mp4");
function myCallBack(o:Object):void{
  if (o.code == "NetStream.Play.Complete"){
        stage.removeChild(fl_Vid);
        nextFrame(); 
  } 
}
```

Fram 2:

```
stop();
int var  part1_cont  =0;
var part1_score =0;

part1_movieClip_1.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, fl_ClickToGoToNextFrame_16);

function fl_ClickToGoToNextFrame_16(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    gotoAndStop(3);
}
```

Fram3 :

```
var  part1_b:int = (int)(Math.random() * 360);
var  part1_a:int = 50;
var part1_c:int = 0 ;
var  part1_d:int = null;
var  part1_tt:int= null;
var  part1_ti:String= null;

if( part1_b >=100)
{
     part1_c=((int)((part1_b-180)/100)*100);
}
else ( part1_b <= 99)
{
      part1_c=(((int)(part1_b-180)/10)*10);
}
movieClip_1.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, fl_RotateContinuously);
function fl_RotateContinuously(event:Event):void
{   
    chose(part1_c);
    if( part1_a>=2){
     part1_a--;
        movieClip_1.rotation+=  part1_a;
        chose(movieClip_1.rotation);
    }else{
        if(movieClip_1.rotation ==  part1_c)
        {
        movieClip_1.rotation ==  part1_c;
        word.text = part1_ti;   
        btn_next.visible = true;
        movieClip_2.visible = false;

    }else{
        movieClip_1.rotation +=1;
        chose(movieClip_1.rotation);
        }
        
    }
}

function chose(du:int):void{
    if( du>0 &&  du<=15)
        { part1_ti = "1";}
        
         if( du>15 &&  du<=30)
        { part1_ti = "2";}
        
         if( du>30 &&  du<=45)
        { part1_ti = "3";}
        
         if( du>45 &&  du<=60)
        { part1_ti = "4";}
        
         if( du>60 &&  du<=75)
        { part1_ti = "5";}
        
         if( du>75 &&  du<=90)
        { part1_ti = "6";}
        
         if( du>90 &&  du<=105)
        { part1_ti = "7";}
        
         if( du>105 &&  du<=120)
        { part1_ti = "8";}
        
         if( du>120 &&  du<=135)
        { part1_ti = "9";}
        
         if( du>135 &&  du<=150)
        { part1_ti = "10";}
        
         if( du>150 &&  du<=165)
        { part1_ti = "11";}
        
        if( du>165 &&  du<=180)
        { part1_ti = "12";}
        
         if( du>-180 &&  du<=-165)
        { part1_ti = "13";}
        
         if( du>-165 &&  du<=-150)
        { part1_ti = "14";}
        
         if( du>-155 &&  du<=-135)
        { part1_ti = "15";}
        
         if( du>-135 &&  du<=-120)
        { part1_ti = "16";}
        
         if( du>-120 &&  du<=-105)
        { part1_ti = "17";}

         if( du>-105 &&  du<=-90)
        { part1_ti = "18";}
        
         if( du>-90 &&  du<=-75)
        { part1_ti = "19";}
        
         if( du>-75 &&  du<=-60)
        { part1_ti = "20";}
        
         if( du>-60 &&  du<=-45)
        { part1_ti = "21";}
        
        
         if( du>-45 &&  du<=-30)
        { part1_ti = "22";}
        
         if( du>-30 &&  du<=-15)
        { part1_ti = "23";}
        
         if( du>-15 &&  du<=0)
        { part1_ti = "24";}
        word.text = part1_ti;   
}
btn_next.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, fl_ClickToGoToAndStopAtFrame_8);

function fl_ClickToGoToAndStopAtFrame_8(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    part1_cont = part1_cont +1;
    part1_b = null;
    part1_a = null;
    part1_c=null ;
    part1_d =null;
    part1_tt=null;
    word.text = "";
    gotoAndStop(7);
}
```

when i change  to use FLVPlayer at Fram1....
Fram1:

```
addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, fl_EnterFrameHandler_6);

function fl_EnterFrameHandler_6(event:Event):void
{
    addChild(part1_player);
    if(part1_player.playheadTime > part1_player.totalTime-0.5 )
    {
    removeChild(part1_player);
    gotoAndStop(6);
    stop();

}
}
```

and it shows error like

> TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object >reference.
> at test_fla::MainTimeline/fl_EnterFrameHandler_12()

Comment: Information isn't enough. Looks like the error is from somewhere else. set your target on AIR for desktop to see the line and frame of the error.

Comment: i very sure error is come form video player .  i try to delete all object form other fram and it can change page but i make a movieClip on page, wan video complete and gotoStop(2)  , movieClip cant use it.